# Pick an image from the Gallery

Tags: android

I have seen a lot of posts about this, and it seems like the code below should work.  I have created an SD Card image and added it to the emulator (and that works fine).

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

It does launch and allow selection of images, but when I click on an image, everything exits and the emulator returns to the home screen, not the back to my app.  My onActivityResult is never called either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I found my issue.  I was launching the gallery from a sub-activity and that sub activity Intent had the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY which prevented the call back from going to that activity.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following intent :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```