# Calling gallery to bring back an image

Tags: android

I'm writing a code for my app, and i got stuck which trying to figure this out.

I want to call `GALLERY` from by app and then if the user selects an image, that image is **brought back to my app for further actions** instead of Gallery opening it.

Plz help me coding this, thanks in advance :)

Comment: look at related questions in right sidebar. There are a bunch of questions that has the answer to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Check here for an answer: [Pick an image from the Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791545/pick-an-image-from-the-gallery?rq=1)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
//intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```