# Pick image from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Activity inside a ActivityGroup. I have the code to get the image:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_PICK);
```

The view to pick the picture is launched and I can select an image. But when it goes back to my app, the onActivityResult is never called (neither in the ActivityGroup nor in the Activity).

I have checked several questions just in case I was missing a receiver and I found this [Pick an image from the Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791545/pick-an-image-from-the-gallery) . But all the flags seem to be off.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be an issue related to the layers of Activies here.

The parent activity should call startActivityForResult, so inside the activity launching the image picker use this instead

```
getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK);
```

The ActivityGroup should then receive the onActivityResult event. Use the LocalAreaManager to then pass the event to the activity.

```
if (YourActivityName.class.equals(getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()){    
    getLocalActivityManager().((YourActivityName) getCurrentActivity()).handleOnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Then inside your activity, create a static class called handleOnActivityResult where you will handle the activity result.